# Make tooltip image align different to the cursor at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I wrote/edited this piece of code to have an image tooltip when hovering on a piece of text. When implementing it in my website I noticed that the website enlarges itself at the bottom to make the image fit.

Is there an easy way to make the cursor align to the bottom of the image when scrolled down to the bottom of the page(?)

```js
this.tooltip = function() {
  /* CONFIG */

  xOffset = 10;
  yOffset = 20;

  // determine popup's distance from the cursor
  /* END CONFIG */

  jQuery("a.tooltip").hover(
    function(e) {
      this.t = this.title;
      this.title = "";
      jQuery("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>" + this.t + "</p>");
      jQuery("#tooltip")
        .css("top", e.pageY - xOffset + "px")
        .css("left", e.pageX + yOffset + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() {
      this.title = this.t;
      jQuery("#tooltip").remove();
    }
  );
  jQuery("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e) {
    jQuery("#tooltip")
      .css("top", e.pageY - xOffset + "px")
      .css("left", e.pageX + yOffset + "px");
  });
};

// starting the script on page load
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  tooltip();
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
}

#tooltip img {
  height: 51.5vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the tooltip will go beyond scrollBottom using tooltip height, and fix offset based on that. this seems to work:

```js
this.tooltip = function() {
  /* CONFIG */

  xOffset = 10;
  yOffset = 20;

  // determine popup's distance from the cursor
  /* END CONFIG */

  jQuery("a.tooltip").hover(
    function(e) {
      this.t = this.title;
      this.title = "";
      jQuery("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>" + this.t + "</p>");
      var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
      if(scrollBottom <= (e.pageY + $('#tooltip').height()))
           xOffset = $('#tooltip').height();
      else
           xOffset = 10;
      jQuery("#tooltip")
        .css("top", e.pageY - xOffset + "px")
        .css("left", e.pageX + yOffset + "px")
        .fadeIn("fast");
    },
    function() {
      this.title = this.t;
      jQuery("#tooltip").remove();
    }
  );
  jQuery("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e) {
    jQuery("#tooltip")
      .css("top", e.pageY - xOffset + "px")
      .css("left", e.pageX + yOffset + "px");
  });
};

// starting the script on page load
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  tooltip();
});
```

```css
#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
}

#tooltip img {
  height: 51.5vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/2ff6b684c6195e0bf24e5b5d35e85a4a/205063011/Commodus.jpeg'/>">TEXTS</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="<img src='http://justsomething.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/guns-replaced-thumbs-up-18.jpg'/>">TEXTS</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check tooltips position using [offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) with document height. If you tooltip is outside the document height then change tooltip position.
eg.

```
if ( (e.pageY - xOffset + tooltip image height) > document height )
{
    jQuery("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e) {
        jQuery("#tooltip")
          .css("bottom", e.pageY - xOffset + "px")
          .css("left", e.pageX + yOffset + "px");
      });
}
```

Comment: The code snippet does not appear to be valid javascript